# Missing class when running the app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-library

I am using a custom Android Library inside an example app. The library has a fragment that must be used from the main activity of the app example.

I have followed the steps to use it from different tutorials, because none of them adjusted 100% to my project.

The fragment has this code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements MapView, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final float ZOOM_INITIAL = 12;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private Location initialLocation;
    private WifiSpotsMapPresenter presenter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wifi_spots_map, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;

        centerInLocation(initialLocation);
    }

    private void centerInLocation(Location location) {
        LatLng myLaLn = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLaLn).zoom(ZOOM_INITIAL).bearing(0).tilt(0).build();
        CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);
        googleMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        init();
        initmap();
    }

    private void initmap() {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
            fragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        initialLocation = new Location("");
        initialLocation.setLongitude(-3.742735);
        initialLocation.setLatitude(40.474886);

        presenter = new WifiSpotsMapPresenterImpl();
        presenter.setView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

And the main activity:

```
import example.sdk.ui.map.view.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

While programming, android studio could resolve the dependencies perfectly, it added me the import as always and I can use the  **implements MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener**  perfectly (you know nothing in red 0 errors while programming).

The problem is when I build/run it. Appears this errors:

```
Error:(9, 83) error: cannot find symbol class OnFragmentInteractionListener
Error:(17, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

How can it be possible if it resolves the class erfectly when programming? What am I missing?

Proguard is disabled.

Comment: How did you place the jar in your classpath? You have to do it over the gradle.build dependencies section of the app module using the jar!

Comment: It's not a .jar it's a android library: `compile project(path: ':blabla.sdk')`

Comment: If it is an AAR you have to access it over a maven repository, which can be local. Here is an old talk from me showing how this works: http://www.slideshare.net/RenMertins/get-startedwithaar-pdfexportrem20141012 Most of this is still current.

Comment: But it is not already compiled, I have the source code in my project.

Comment: Then I don't have a clou what you are doing there. A local library module should be referenced as simple as you described. sorry

Comment: No matter, thank you. :)

Comment: Did you include that library (settings.gradle) in your project (include ':blabla')?

Comment: @Blehi This is my settings.gradle include `':app', ':blabla.sdk'`